# Как можно передать два параметра в URL?

Tags: python, django

Имеется следующее представление (*view.py*):

```
def addlike(request, article_id, comment_id)
```

И url-паттерн (*urls.py*):

```
url(r'^page/(\d+)/$', 'article.views.article')
```

Как нужно изменить паттерн, чтобы в функцию передавался еще один параметр?

Comment: Полагаю, `Comment` связан с `Article`. Зачем дополнительно передавать `article_id`?

Comment: `url(r'^page/(\d+)/(\d+)/$`.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы передать несколько параметров в url, проще всего воспользоваться именованными группами. Цитата из [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#named-groups):

> ```
> from django.conf.urls import url
>
> from . import views
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
>     url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
>     url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
>     url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/$', views.article_detail),
> ]
> ```
>
> Запрос к `/articles/2005/03/` вызовет функцию
>
> ```
> views.month_archive(request, year='2005', month='03')
> ```
>
> Запрос к
>   `/articles/2003/03/03/` вызовет функцию
>
> ```
> views.article_detail(request, year='2003', month='03', day='03')
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
url(r'^(?P<article_id>\d+)/(?P<comment_id>\d+)/$', views.addlike, name='caddlike'),
```

Comment: (@alexander-barakin нехорошо редактировать ответы, меняя их суть)

Comment: @andreymal, суть — в отсутствии четырёх пробелов в начале строки?

Comment: В именованных группах, которые в версии 1 отсутствовали.

Comment: Да действительно <text> пропустил.

Comment: Хотя если это движок SO так их неаккуратно вырезал и меня в заблуждение ввёл, то это какой-то баг получается.

Comment: @andreymal это не баг, но в заблуждение вы себя ввели, да. Правка состоит из добавления 4х пробелов. SO реагирует на `<...>`, если это размечено как простой текст (а не как код), как на тег.

Comment: Регулярка то правильная, мб -1 уберете?

Comment: @Regent ну вообще несуществующие теги, думаю, было бы неплохо не вырезать.)

Comment: @AlexKarahanidi да кто его знает - откуда минус появился...  Есть вероятность, что из-за правки. Хотя этот баг и не доказан.

Comment: Просто я указывал <text> а он пропал вместе с <>

Comment: @Regent Минус был выставлен автоматически пользователем Community в по результатам правки. Вопрос на Мете уже есть, в ближайшее время отпишусь там.